# Varnish triggering 503 without timeout

Tags: apache, varnish

**Disclaimer**: we are in a moment migrating some servers from Windows to Linux, so you will see some unusual architecture here.

I have the following communication between our backend servers:

Client -> Apache Httpd (decrypts SSL - running Windows Server) -> Varnish Cache (forward proxy and HTTP Cache - Running Ubuntu 16) -> Apache Tomcat (Application Server - Running Windows server).

We have something like 200 users active at peak time and an Ajax call that verify user connection every second.

From time to time, our clients receives a 503 (backend fetch failed - guru meditation) from this Ajax request. I first thought it would be some kind of application server slowdown so I increase timeouts as follows:

```
backend xxx {
    .host = "<%= $HOST_API %>";
    .port = "<%= $HOST_PORT %>";
    .first_byte_timeout = 1200s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 1200s;
    .connect_timeout  = 10s;
}
```

But the problem continued to happen. So I investigated modifying the Apache Access Log to log the time the request spent on the backend:

The configuration was:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b **%T/%D**" commomWithTime
```

So the time will be shown as **TIME_IN_SECONDS/TIME_IN_MILISECONDS**

When I get a 503 error, I will receive the following line:

```
200.201.175.53 - - [11/Sep/2017:17:16:06 -0300] "GET /sistema/verificarDesconexao?_=1505154046861 HTTP/1.1" 503 286 **0/0**
```

So Apache is telling me Varnish returned a 503 error instantaneously! In this case, it is impossible to be a timeout error, right?

Here one Varnishlog message with the 503 error (I had to modify some sensitive parts):

```
*   << BeReq    >> 179699819
-   Begin          bereq 179699818 pass
-   Timestamp      Start: 1505161516.061772 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /sistema/verificarDesconexao?_=1505153165280
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: 10.1.1.135
-   BereqHeader    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
-   BereqHeader    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
-   BereqHeader    Referer: https://www.sistema.com.br/sistema/
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
-   BereqHeader    Cookie: JSESSIONID=0334D2460BD8E8AE9299E546AEB2838F; logo=Axis; idiomaSelecionado=pt_BR
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: www.sistema.com.br
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Server: www.sistema.com.br
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: [IP], 10.1.1.177
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 179699819
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   FetchError     no backend connection
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1505161516.062073 0.000301 0.000301
-   Timestamp      Error: 1505161516.062079 0.000307 0.000006
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   503
-   BerespReason   Service Unavailable
-   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
-   BerespHeader   Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2017 20:25:16 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      503
-   ObjReason      Backend fetch failed
-   ObjHeader      Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2017 20:25:16 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Server: Varnish
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   ObjHeader      Retry-After: 5
-   Length         286
-   BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
-   End
```

Which other cases a Varnish 503 error would happen and how should I identify and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your varnish cannot reach or connect your backend server as the log says

```
FetchError no backend connection
```

can you check that you can ping your backend from your varnish and inititate an http connection ?

Comment: From thousands of connections made, just some receives this 503 error.
I mean, all clients receives this messages at the same time for a second or less.

Comment: Maybe a network temporary unavailability? Is there a way to validate this?

Comment: do you have tracks of your backend health in the logs? try to grep sick

Comment: I didn't setup a probe. I still can do it? How can I track backend health logs?

Comment: you can still define a probe. define it and link it to your backend declaration. the health checks will appear in your varnishlog.

Comment: what are your varnish startup parameters? are you under heavy load?

Comment: ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :<%= $varnish_port %> -T localhost:<%= $varnish_admin_port %> -f /varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,<%= $varnish_memory_allocation %>m